# Convert String "1/1/1970" to a date object formatted as "19700101000000"?

Tags: java, date

I am writing Junit tests to verify data entered after it has been transformed into a different format.  How would I convert a String like "1/1/1970" into a date object formatted like 19700101000000?  I tried this:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Date date = format.parse("1/1/1970");
```

But "1/1/1970" throws an `Unparseable date` ParseException.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use *different* `DateFormat`s to parse and to format.  Right now you're taking `"1/1/1970"` and trying to read it with the date format "yyyyMMddHHmmss".  You'll need to *parse* with the format `MM/dd/yyyy`, get out a `Date`, and *then* format it with your format "yyyyMMddHHmmss".

Comment: Great!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse using one formatter, then reformat using another. Here's code for old style, and for new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API built into Java 8 and later.

```
String input = "1/1/1970";

// Using SimpleDateFormat
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy").parse(input);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(date));

// Using Java 8 java.time
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu"));
System.out.println(localDate.atStartOfDay().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss")));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Louis Wasserman indicated, format.parse the input date String to a Date object.  Then use that Date object as input to another SimpleDateFormat object.

Something like this :

```
public class DateFormatTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputDate = args[0];
    java.util.Date d = null;
    java.text.DateFormat inputDateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    java.text.DateFormat outputDateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    try {
        d = inputDateFormat.parse(intputDate);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
        System.err.println("something horrible went wrong!");
    }
    String output = outputDateFormat.format(d);
    System.out.println("The input date of: " + inputDate + " was re-formatted to: " + output);
  }
}
```

Providing "1/1/1970" as the input parameter, the output is:

```
The input date of: 1/1/1970 was re-formatted to: 19700101000000
```